# generate a random number for a credit card

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to use this method to generate a credit card number of 16 digits that starts with 4
if the issuerSymbol equals ISSUER AMER EXPRESS. the random number has to start with 3 if issuerSymbol equals ISSUER VISA and 5 it it ISSUER MASTER CARD.

```
 public Integer getIssuerCode(String issuerSymbol){
            int randomInteger = 0;
          Random   random = new Random();


    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            randomInteger = random.nextInt();
         if (issuerSymbol.equals(ISSUER_AMER_EXPRESS)) {

         }

          else {
             System.out.println("error");
         }
         if(issuerSymbol.equals(ISSUER_VISA)){

         }
          else{
              System.out.println("error");
          }
           if (issuerSymbol.equals(ISSUER_MASTER_CARD)){

         }
           else{
                 System.out.println("error");
           } 
    }

     return randomInteger;
        }
```

Comment: So what is the question?  It looks like you've hardly started, are you stuck somewhere specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem with you if and else. You need to understand that it will go in else if the if is not true the code should be changed to them to if else if and else ...

```
if (issuerSymbol.equals(ISSUER_AMER_EXPRESS)) {

} else if(issuerSymbol.equals(ISSUER_VISA)){

} else if (issuerSymbol.equals(ISSUER_MASTER_CARD)){

} else {
             System.out.println("error");
}
```

Another suggestion the `Random` class includes [`nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) which (per the Javadoc) *Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed `int` value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

```
randomInteger = 3 + random.nextInt() % 3;
```

or

```
randomInteger = 3 + random.nextInt(3);
```

this will ensure that you randomInteger is always in 3 or 4 or 5

Comment: I could not get this to work randomInteger = 2 + random.nextInt() % 3;

Answer (score 0):

With 16 digits, the biggest number for the credit card you can get is 5999999999999999, while the biggest number int can represent is 2^31-1 or 2,147,483,647, so I'd recommend using BigInteger instead.  Depending on how you plan on using randomInteger, it can either be a BigInteger or a String.

Since you're trying to get a 16 digit number but the first is determined to be either 3, 4, or 5, that means you need 15 random integers.  You can set `randomInteger` based on the issuer symbol using your if-else if statements, then you can use a for loop that picks 15 random integers and appends them to randomInteger.

```
//assuming randomInteger is already equal to 3, 4, or 5 
//and randomInteger is of type BigInteger
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  randomInteger = randomInteger.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(10);
  randomInteger = randomInteger.add(BigInteger.valueOf(random.nextInt(10));
}
```

If you wanted randomInteger to be a string, just concatenate the first digit to an empty string ("") and keep concatenating a random digit.